# How do you say that "while" is frequently followed by past continuous?

Tags: translation

I usually explain grammar in private lessons and there's an expression I would like to know.
For example, I was trying to explain that when you use *while*, it is frequently followed by past continuous.
In Spain we say, "Cuando utilizas while, normalmente **va con** past continuous".
I would like to know if the literal translation is "When you use while, it usually **goes with** past continuous"
Or what is the most common way to say, that *while* is frequently followed by past continuous ?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Goes with' works in English, too, in a language context. _To conjugate regular verbs that end in -ar, you need to remove the infinitive -ar ending from the infinitive and add the unique ending that **goes with** each subject pronoun to the stem._ BBC Spanish

Comment: No such rule I know. *While* goes with all kinds of verbs: While I write this, While eating, While I will allow ...

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thanks, nice example as well :)

Comment: @YosefBaskin I was referring to the expression "goes with", but the question was solved thanks ^^

Comment: If you're not making claims about grammaticality, _is often used with_ is a nice, generic description that can be used in many situations.

Comment: Cuando utilizas while va con past continuous o el pasado simples. He drooled while he slept. He drooled while he was sleeping.

Comment: What's wrong with "While is frequently followed by past continuous"?

Comment: @HotLicks Since you ask, what's wrong is that (a) "past continuous" is just the continuous construction with a past tense verb, not a tense of its own; (b) "followed by" uses the beads-on-a-string metaphor for sentence construction, which ignores constituent boundaries and uses only rough approximations of rules; and (c) a statement like that can be useful to a tutor who observes a particular student's behavior, but they're useless as general rules,, like "_to_ is often followed by _be_".

Answer (score 1):

'Goes with' works in English, too, in a language context.

> To conjugate regular verbs that end in -ar, you need to remove the
> infinitive -ar ending from the infinitive and add the unique ending
> that goes with each subject pronoun to the stem.

[Spanish present tense with '-ar', '-er' and '-ir' - BBC Spanish](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/z39h7yc/articles/zdxs3dm)

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to explain that when you use while, it is frequently followed by past continuous.

This is good general advice, and I note the use of "frequently".

While/Whilst take a continuous as it implies a durative action and there is an usually a contemporaneous secondary action.

I suggest

""While" clauses often, but not always, take a verb in the continuous form."

Answer (score 0):

You could say that *while* usually **takes** a past continuous verb. [TFD defines this sense of take as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/take)

> To require or have as a fitting or proper accompaniment

It gives the example:

> *Transitive verbs take a direct object.*